# IDLE Tkinter GUI widgets won't open when I run them? (Windows 7)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing a program that uses the Tkinter widgets (ie. Frame, buttons, labels etc...) and everything works fine on my school computers (python 2.6 running on Ubuntu.), but on my Windows 7 computer at home, no error messages show up but the program doesn't open. 
This is what I have written to set up the main frame:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
mainframe = Frame(root)
mainframe.pack()
mainframe.grid()
```

The program then displays some labels and buttons (I don't believe that they're part of the problem). Again, the program works without any problems on my school computer which uses Python 2.6 and runs on Ubuntu. When I run the program at home, no error messages show up, but the Tkinter windows don't pop up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Put this on the last line of youre program:

```
root.mainloop()
```

this will start the event loop and actually show you're window

that will probably fix the problem it worked on my computer

Answer (score 0):

you do

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1000x1000')
root.mainloop()
```